# Console.log(err) is crashing my website

Tags: node.js, database, rest, routes, console.log

I'm currently a student studying Web Development with Node. I recently was reviewing RESTful routes. I was building a blog site to do so. I was setting up a route to show a specific blog "/blogs/:id" which lets you see all the contents of a blog. Here's the route:

```
app.get("/blogs/:id", function(req, res){
    blog.findById(req.params.id, function(err, blog){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else{
            res.render("show", {body: blog});
        }
    })
})
```

When I access the route using the browser, it loads forever and I get the following error in the terminal:

```
{ CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "app.css" at path "_id" for model "blog"
    at MongooseError.CastError (/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTful/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/cast.js:29:11)
    at ObjectId.cast (/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTful/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:158:13)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTful/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:724:12)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTful/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1113:15)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTful/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1103:15)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTful/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1082:15)
    at cast (/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTful/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast.js:303:32)
    at Query.cast (/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTful/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:3355:12)
    at Query._castConditions (/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTful/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1327:10)
    at Query._findOne (/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTful/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1552:8)
    at process.nextTick (/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTful/node_modules/kareem/index.js:333:33)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "app.css" at path "_id" for model "blog"',
  name: 'CastError',
  stringValue: '"app.css"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'app.css',
  path: '_id',
  reason: undefined,
  model: 
   { [Function: model]
     hooks: Kareem { _pres: [Object], _posts: [Object] },
     base: 
      Mongoose {
        connections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        modelSchemas: [Object],
        options: [Object],
        _pluralize: [Function: pluralize],
        plugins: [Object] },
     modelName: 'blog',
     model: [Function: model],
     db: 
      NativeConnection {
        base: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        replica: false,
        options: null,
        otherDbs: [],
        relatedDbs: {},
        states: [Object],
        _readyState: 1,
        _closeCalled: false,
        _hasOpened: true,
        _listening: false,
        _connectionOptions: [Object],
        client: [Object],
        name: 'restful_routing_revision',
        '$initialConnection': [Object],
        db: [Object] },
     discriminators: undefined,
     '$appliedMethods': true,
     '$appliedHooks': true,
     schema: 
      Schema {
        obj: [Object],
        paths: [Object],
        aliases: {},
        subpaths: {},
        virtuals: [Object],
        singleNestedPaths: {},
        nested: {},
        inherits: {},
        callQueue: [],
        _indexes: [],
        methods: {},
        methodOptions: {},
        statics: {},
        tree: [Object],
        query: {},
        childSchemas: [],
        plugins: [Object],
        s: [Object],
        _userProvidedOptions: {},
        options: [Object],
        '$globalPluginsApplied': true,
        _requiredpaths: [] },
     collection: 
      NativeCollection {
        collection: [Object],
        opts: [Object],
        name: 'blogs',
        collectionName: 'blogs',
        conn: [Object],
        queue: [],
        buffer: false,
        emitter: [Object] },
     Query: { [Function] base: [Object] },
     '$__insertMany': [Function],
     '$init': Promise { [Object], catch: [Function] } } }
```

But for some reason, when I change the callback to be the following:

```
app.get("/blogs/:id", function(req, res){
        blog.findById(req.params.id, function(err, blog){
            if(err){
                res.redirect("/")
            } else{
                res.render("show", {body: blog});
            }
        })
    })
```

The website works perfectly fine. I also tried removing the header from the show.ejs(the file being rendered when accessing the route) while keeping the `console.log(err)` and it also solved the problem. I tried removing the header because the header contains the tag that links the app.css file which I saw mentioned in the error. I would like to know what's wrong in `console.log(err)` with the css file.
p.s. I am using Expres for the routes and mongoose to access the MongoDB database. "blog" is the array of blogs. Incase you want to take a look at my show.ejs file, here it is:

```
<% include partials/header %>

<h1><%= body.title%></h1>
<img src="<%=body.image%>">
<p><%=body.body%></p>
<div><%=body.created%></div>

<% include partials/footer %>
```

And if you want to take a look at the app.css file, here it is:

```
img{
    max-width: 600px;
    width: 600px;
}
```

And if you want to take a look at the header.ejs file, here it si:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Blogs Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
    </head>
    <body>
```

Here is the full app.js file (the file containing the routes):

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    mongo = require("mongoose"),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    expressSanitizer = require("express-sanitizer"),
    methodOverride = require("method-override");

mongo.connect("mongodb://localhost/restful_routing_revision");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(expressSanitizer());
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

var blogSchema = new mongo.Schema({
    title: String,
    body: String,
    image: String,
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now} 
});

var blog = mongo.model("blog", blogSchema);


app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("landing");
});

app.get("/blogs", function(req, res){
    blog.find({}, function(err, body){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            res.render("index", {blogs: body})
        }
    })
})

app.get("/dogs/new", function(req, res){
    res.render("new");
})

app.post("/dogs", function(req, res){
    var blogBody = req.body.blog;
    blog.create(blogBody, function(err, body){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            res.redirect("/blogs")
        }
    })
})

app.get("/blogs/:id", function(req, res){
    blog.findById(req.params.id, function(err, blog){
        if(err){
            // res.redirect("/")
            console.log(err)
        } else{
            res.render("show", {body: blog});
        }
    })
})

// blog.findById(req.params.id, function(err, blog){
//       if(err){
//           res.redirect("/");
//       } else {
//           res.render("show", {body: blog});
//       }
//   });
// });

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("The Server has Started!!!!");
})
```

There are alot of npm packages on top that I'm planning to use later. And I know that the blog Schema isn't well formatted. I also tried doing `console.log(err)` and `res.redirect("/")` at the same time, I arrive to the show page but still get the same error.

Comment: To completely answer your questions, I would need to see the 'partials/header' file.    The 'it loads forever' issue in your browser is because you _have_ to have res.[something] in every endpoint, even if you get an error.  Can give more detail in an answer if you post the headers file, but this might be enough for you to get it sorted.

Comment: Here is the header file: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Blogs Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
    </head>
    <body>

Comment: Can you share the code under your router `/blogs/:id`. And as @HenryMueller mentioned above, loading forever is because of that. Error seems because of some mapping mismatch between your code and mongoose model.

Comment: @eduPeeth I just updated the post and now it contains all the code of the file containing the routes

Comment: @HenryMueller i just updated the post with the info u needed.

Comment: @HenryMueller Thanks, the error was solved by just adding the "/" before the app.css when I linked it in the header. I would like to mention that even when I replaced console.log(err) with res.redirect("/"), it wouldn't redirect me to the home page, instead it would do what it's supposed to do while still printing the error in the terminal. What i can conclude from this is that the if(err) isnt being triggered, but accessing this route is triggering an error not related. But, anyways it was fixed by the post you linked. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I can't explain how redirect to / would work that way without seeing it in action--sounds strange.  But the way that the syntax error in the header html triggers a find query on your model is strange too! (I would expect it fail in a more graceful way.)  Glad it is working now and hope the mysteries don't come back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the CastError, I don't know what is going on in the underlying ejs code that causes it to try to run a Mongo query with the css filename, but this post explains how to fix your syntax (read the answer's comments about using a relative path for the css name):

[NodeJS error when rendering page:Cast to ObjectId failed for value "styles.css" at path "_id"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36040985/nodejs-error-when-rendering-pagecast-to-objectid-failed-for-value-styles-css)

I think that will get rid of the error in your endpoint.

**For the headline question about crashing the server and the observation that:**

> When I access the route using the browser, it loads forever

is because the endpoint does not ever issue a response to the client when you get an error.  All endpoints need to respond to the client in some way.  In your case, the documented[1](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) recommendation is to call the Express middleware function next:

```
blog.findById(req.params.id, function(err, blog){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        next(err);
    } else{
```

The next function will return an error result to the client browser.  You need to use next because the .find function of your Mongoose model is asynchronous and Expresses next function is designed to deal with this correctly.

A separate detail, from what you posted, your Express server is most likely not crashing.  It is logging the console message with an error just like you asked then continuing on waiting for new requests (logging an error to the console is perfectly ok!).  If it crashed, you would likely get a 500 error page in the browser and the node process would terminate. I mention this in hopes to help future debugging.  I think if you had searched on the client issue of the endpoint not returning, you would likely have found an existing answer about endpoints that never return to the client (this is a common issue to run into when getting started).  I hope that helps!

[Express Error Handling Doc](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

Answer (score 2):

Just use absolute path `/style.css` instead of relative path `style.css`.

**Explanation:**

You are using `app.use(express.static("public"));` which will make the route `app.get("/blogs/:id", function(req, res){...});` when triggered it tries to render `style.css` in your html link tag because it meets the route path as `/blogs/style.css` since your public `folder` is in the same level with `blogs`, so by putting `/` in front of `style.css` makes it an absolute path, so execution will start the path from the seed, and not continue down from `blogs`.

Another *solution* is to just handle triggering the route `blogs/style.css` by actually creating a route for it as follows:

```
app.get('/campgrounds/app.css', function(req, res) {
    break;
});
```

Make sure to put it before the route `app.get("/blogs/:id", function(req, res){...});` to be executed first, if triggered.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to put this line at the end**

In app.js file
cut this line and paste it at the end:

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
```